# How do you assign a UUID in Swift?

Tags: swift, mvvm, viewmodel, uuid

I am trying to follow the Model View ViewModel format for SwiftUI, but am running into an issue with UUID. I have an object of type `TimeCode` that has an attribute `id` of type UUID (`TimeCode` is created in xcdatamodels as a CoreData model). In order to create a `TimeCodeViewModel` object, I need to assign the `id` attribute in `TimeCodeViewModel` with the same UUID from the original `TimeCode` object. I therefore created this class definition to do so:

```
class TimeCodeViewModel: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var fullName = ""
    
    
    init(timeCode: TimeCode) {
        self.id = timeCode.id
        self.fullName = timeCode.fullName
    }
    
    // class methods
}
```

However, I get a compile time error saying that UUID is a get-only property. This makes sense, since you shouldn't be able to reassign the unique ID of an object to a different object, but in this case I am actually trying to describe the same object. Is it possible to assign `self.id` with the same UUID?

I guess another approach could be to make the UUID a string and then assign it to the view model, but is it then possible to convert the string back into a UUID? For example, I want to fetch the original `TimeCode` from CoreData using the UUID from the `TimeCodeViewModel` so I can save edits to other attributes of the `TimeCode`.

Comment: This isn't enough code to solve the problem. Please show the line which the compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be interesting to see how the TimeCode Class looks like. I don't think that the id is set correctly. If you want a unique identifier as a String add the following to generate one:

```
var id: String = UUID().uuidString
```

You can share the string and therefore reference to the same object.

EDIT:
Regarding the new information, changing the class to the following might be an idea:

```
class TimeCodeViewModel: Identifiable {
   var id: UUID {
      return timeCode.id
   }
   var fullName = ""
   private var timeCode: TimeCode

   init(timeCode: TimeCode) {
      self.timeCode = timeCode
      self.fullName = timeCode.fullName
   }
   // class methods
 }
```

Comment: `TimeCode` is created in xcdatamodel, and `id` is assigned to type UUID. I would rather not use a string since storing `id` as UUID takes less space and is faster to query. Is there anyway to make the uuidstring a UUID (i.e. go in the opposite direction).

Comment: @greatxp117 What about clarifying your question by adding information like this to it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it would actually be relevant. It seems like your idea of just having the view model have a `TimeCode` as a data member is the best approach. Thank you!